# bbmap change atomic vector value

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap

I'm using `bbmap` and `ggmap` to plot a map of Manhattan, New York, USA. My code is:

```
mh_bb <- getbb('manhattan new york usa')
mh_map <- get_map(mh_bb, source='google')
ggmap(mh_map)
```

However, I would like to lower the minimum value of the latitude. I tried:

```
mh_bb$min[2] <- 40.6
```

but I get the error that  `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.

Could someone tell me how I can change the minimum latitude? Thanks!